# Creating transient table with copy grants as option

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

The requirement is to create table in Snowflake by using an Airflow JOB.

```
create or replace transient table humanities_timesheet copy grants as
(
    worker_name varchar(300),
    employee_id varchar(20)
)
```

Syntax error: unexpected 'worker_name'.
syntax error line 3 at position 25 unexpected ','. (line 12)

without the  copy grants as the code works and table gets created under the right schema.

When I used CTE was able to create transient tables with the copy grants as option

```
create
or replace transient table dq_mart.working.reconciliation_workday_worker_position copy grants as 
with workday_worker_position as (
select * from humanities
)
```

Any suggestions on using copy grants as when creating a new transient table would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you are creating a table that doesn’t reference another table (i.e. you aren’t cloning, using COPY … AS… etc), where do you think COPY GRANTS is going to be copying grants from?

Answer (score 0):

Just a problem of order into your syntax.
This works :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRANSIENT TABLE humanities_timesheet  (
  worker_name varchar(300),
  employee_id varchar(20)
) COPY GRANTS
;
```

Documentation here : [CREATE TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html)